# Cucumber JS child_process in feature step

Tags: node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am trying to write some CucumberJS features, which will test a NodeJS command line application I am creating, however I am running into problems being able to execute a `child_process` within a feature step.

Simply to get a proof of concept working I am attempting to execute the `ls -l` command.

The code that I have is;

```
var ChildProcess = require('child_process');

function execCmd() {

  console.log('Testing command...');
  var bin = ChildProcess.exec('ls -l', { timeout: 5 }, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('executing...');
    console.log(error);
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
  });

  bin.on('exit', function(code) {
    console.log('Code: ' + code);
  });
}

module.exports = function() {

  this.Given(/^I am on the command line$/, function(callback) {
    execCmd();
    callback();
  });

}
```

Executing `cucumber-js` does not output anything from the executed command. The output is as follows;

```
Testing command...
.

1 scenario (1 passed)
1 step (1 passed)
```

But if I simply call `execCmd()` after the function definition, removing the `module.exports` block and run `node cli.js` I see the output (i.e. the file listing) correctly.

I have seen [how to access stdout,stderr, and error in cucumber.js step definition using nodejs child_process exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466659/how-to-access-stdout-stderr-and-error-in-cucumber-js-step-definition-using-node), which doesn't answer the question and is simply states how to execute a command and nothing specific to running this within a CucumberJS step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is due to a couple things:

1. The *callback* is invoked in the **Given**, essentially exiting the cucumberjs program prior to finishing the child process execution.
2. The exit delegate passed into *exec()* is being overridden when assigning an 'on' event handler.

I believe this will solve your issue:

```
var ChildProcess = require('child_process');

function execCmd(cb) {

  console.log('Testing command...');
  var bin = ChildProcess.exec('ls -l', {timeout:5}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('executing...');
    console.log(error);
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    cb();
  });
}

module.exports = function() {

  this.Given(/^I am on the command line$/, function(callback) {
    execCmd(callback);
  });

}
```